# Does function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}+\sin(x^2y)\cos(z-7)$ belong to space $L^k(B)$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$?

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Does function $$f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}+\sin(x^2y)\cos(z-7)$$
belong to space $L^k(B)$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$?

where $B(0,1)$ is a sphere in $\Bbb{R}^3$ centered at origin with radius $1$, and $\|\cdot\|$ is euclidean norm in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

I know that $f \in L^k(B)$ if $$\int_B |f(x,y,z)|^k \, ds < \infty$$

and since I am integrating over a sphere I use spherical coordinates to solve the integral.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{r} + \sin(r^3\sin^3\theta\cos^2\phi\sin\phi)\cos(r\cos\theta-7) \right)^k r^2\sin\theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\phi$$

but now I am left with some complicated integrals so my questions are, is this a correct approach? And isn't there a better one?

(I haven't found similar solved problems in textbooks nor on the internet so I would also appreciate some resources or links)

Comment: It's enough to study the integrability of $g(\mathbf{x}) = 1/\|\mathbf{x}\|$; the remaining part is a bounded continuous function.

Comment: Just think about what is the first value of $k$ that gets you a diverging $dr$ integral

Comment: @Rigel So you mean I can write the $f$ function as a sum of two functions $f(x,y,z) = g(x, y, z) + h(x, y, z)$ and study them separately? Like $\int_B |g(x, y, z)|^k \, dp < \infty$ and $\int_B |h(x, y, z)|^k \, dt < \infty$ and if they both are $< \infty$ then I can say the function $f \in L^k(B)$?

Comment: Since $B$ is bounded, and $h\in L^\infty(B)$, then $f\in L^k$ if and only if $g\in L^k$. Indeed, $|g| - M \leq |f| \leq |g| + M$, where $M = \|h\|_\infty$, and, for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $|g| + c \in L^k(B)$ if and only if $g\in L^k(B)$.